# Recreate Kanye's new album cover in TeX

Tags: fun

Kanye West just published the cover for his new album. To me, it looks like a figure with captions that went horribly wrong. Can somebody recreate this image in TeX?

[image: 'The Life of Pablo' Album Cover]

Comment: Why is that question downvoted? It looks like a perfectly valid {fun} question to me.

Comment: @Clement: I think [tag:do-this-for-me]-style questions don't add much value to the community. Who will come here and search how to replicate Kanye West's album cover one year from now. Even if they do, one may generalize this and post any album cover containing text and request it be replicated... and that's a bit much/ridiculous. It also shows no research effort.

Comment: Depending on where you live, that could be a violation of copyright....

Comment: Why replicate something which looks as if it has gone `horribly wrong`?

Comment: And how is this different than the football field question that has 19 and 10 voted answers? Please don't make legal excuses for your own preference. For everybody dying to teach me the rules read this first and the linked ones http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4267/our-do-it-for-me-and-draw-it-for-me-comments-dont-reflect-our-hypocrisy-can-th

Comment: @percusse -- I don't know why people bother to answer those questions either. (I imagine each person has their own personal reason for answering the draw-X-for-me questions ... like, hey, it would be cool to have PSTricks-drawn football field, or, hey, it would be cool to write text like on Kanye's new LP, or, hey I do want to (learn how to better) use Asymptote to draw Xs and Ys.) Although I am a pretty generous voter, I usually leave such questions and answers unvoted-on.... The main exception is if I rely on an answer to help me with something I was struggling with; if the answer helped, +1

Comment: @percusse -- Your comment seems to answer a question I never asked. But, sure: it is a question that can be answered. (Where I live though it would violate copyright.) I've only ever downvoted spam. I'd say neutrality is exhibited through non-voting, which was my point. But you asked why people answered only some questions that were formally the same as others, and I tried to suggest why I think it happens. And just because people answer the question about the football field should have no bearing on the 'oughtness' of whether they answer this question or vote for it (or downvote it, too!).

Comment: @jon It is a response to *I don't know why people bother.....*

Comment: @percusse -- Ah, I see. Hard to disagree with it, then; though that is a pretty thin account of motivation. I think the reasons are actually a little deeper than that (along the lines I suggested; but I'd add boredom, too, as you suggest in meta). And I agree with the downvoting, but why on earth shouldn't people not 'touch the question' whenever they please? If they don't want to answer (or vote), so be it!

Answer (score 5):

Well you get the idea, even his name makes me bored

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\myeightlines{\foreach \x in {0,...,7}{
  \node[font=\bfseries\sffamily] at (0,0.5*\x) {THE LIFE OF PABLO};}
}
\foreach \x/\y in {1/1,1/4.8,1/8,4.5/0.5,4.5/3}{
  \begin{scope}[shift={(\x+0.1*rand,\y+0.1*rand)}]
    \myeightlines
  \end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]